# Can you find out the ui panel name a property is listed inside with python?

Tags: python, panel

Say for example, I'm querying the (viewport display) "Color" property inside the "World Properties" tab which is listed inside the panel labelled "Viewport Display" with python. From there on, is it possible to somehow get the panel name ("Viewport Display") with python?

Comment: A property can be displayed in an arbitrary number of panels and doesn't hold a reference to the layout elements it is part of. You would have to traverse every existing panel and check if one of its layout elements displays that particular field. Could you elaborate on your usecase, maybe you can achieve it by other means ?

Comment: Ah, I see. 
To elaborate further: I'm trying to query a few non-custom properties, and I'd like to display their value and the "place" where they can be found in a custom ui panel of mine.

Comment: That's an interesting challenge ! but unless you have dozens of such properties you might as well do it by hand, because some properties can be displayed in different places in the UI. Take for instance the transforms, you can find them in the 3D viewport and in the properties editor

Comment: I totally get your approach, but let's say it wouldn't just be a few. Can you think of a way to dynamically get the panel name? It would be absolutely fine if the property appears in more than one place.